# I want to call a function with parameters from client side to server side using google appmaker

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function with parameters inside from client side to server side using google appmaker. 
You can check the functions below:

CLIENT-SIDE:

```
    google.script.run
        .addRecord(Prof_email,row.Student_email,param2);
```

Server-Side:

```
    function addRecord(teacherEmail, studentEmail,reasonAbsence){
       var row = [];
       var Record = app.models.Alerts.newRecord();
       Record.teacherEmail = teacherEmail;
       Record.studentEmail = studentEmail;
       Record.date = new Date();
       Record.reasonAbsence = reasonAbsence;
       row.push(Record);
       return row;

    }
```

The idea is to get data from the client side and add data to a table in server side using the parameters inside the function, which is called from the client-side.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The code above does not work. The parameters are not passed on the table. I do not know why

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The main problem is that the data is not showed in the table. Also the parameters are not passed.

Comment: Which model you used for the datasource? To my understanding, you also want to show the table on appmaker UI right? Maybe try to use calculated model? and add the sever-side function to the datasource query. As your reference, see one of the datasource in "Project Tracker" https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/project-tracker/ Hope it could help!